# access to activity from BroadCastReceiver.onReceive

Tags: android

Im developping alarm application.

I'm using listview on activity to reserve alarm.
after application finish BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() method, 
I want to remove check of list.

But i dont know how to access to activity.
anybody knows?

The following is my code:

```
public class Activity_001 extends ListActivity {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceiverGenerateAlarm.class);
        intent.setAction(Conf.GenerateAlarm);
        intent.putExtra(cal,timerList.get(0).getCal().getTimeInMillis(）)

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
0);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)
(this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE));

        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
timerList.get(0).getCal().getTimeInMillis(), sender);

}
```

.

```
public class ReceiverGenerateAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {

                String action = intent.getAction();
                if(action.equals(Conf.GenerateAlarm)) {

                        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
                        long cal = bundle.getLongArray("cal");

                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.setTimeInMillis(cal);

                        MediaPlayer_inherit_Class tm = new MediaPlayer_inherit_Class(cal); 
                        tm.play();

                        //in here, wanna access alarm reservation list and remove check of list. as application has executed.
                        //set next alarm, if needed. 
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should be using a SQLite db to store your "alarm reservations". If this is true, simply update your db entries in your `onReceive()`. When the `Activity` is restored, it should check for changes to the alarm db table and update the UI accordingly.

One alternative is to call `startActivity()` from your `onReceive()` with [bundled extras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). Possibly pass a row id or time-stamp to query with `Intent.putExtra()`.

Another is to put the `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: every call of startActivity() generate new activity ? 
as i want existing activity's ListView and want to update, i didnt use startActivity().
instead of it, i put BroadCastReceiver in my Activity.

and now application is working fine. thank you very much !

Comment: Glad to help! BTW - startActivity() only generates a "new" activity in certain situations. For example, if you set launchMode="singleInstance",  the existing activity will be brought to the front, and onNewIntent() will be fired. Please remember to accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Why the ans is not up voted or accepted? thanks for help